# get ios Accounts information

Tags: ios, account, user-accounts

I am trying to get Account information in my app on iOS. 
For example, if I have google account saved in Accounts I would like to get informations about it in my app. Is this posible and how if it is.

Marko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to access account information from already setup email accounts on your device then i am afraid you can't.

Comment: thanks, but what about Account.framework, can I do something whit it?

Comment: @Marko: Please consider the following url which says up to IOS 5 Account framework only supports Twitter account, not sure about IOS6 and above  http://www.peterfriese.de/the-accounts-and-twitter-framework-on-ios-5/

Answer (score 0):

Deepesh is correct about not having access to a user's account information, but the [AddressBook](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/), [AddressBookUI](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007082) and [EventKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html) APIS will allow you access to the user's data provided by those accounts.